# Slim middleware - not receiving next callable

Tags: php, slim, middleware

I have the bellow middleware, and I'm trying to invoke it for routes that need to be authenticated. When __invoke fires, the third argument is an empty array instead of next callable middleware from the stack.My other middlewares work fine, and the only difference to this one is the constructor. Could that be the issue?

I also assume that previous middleware stack works well, because when I remove this one from the stack, the application works as expected.

Error I get is `Fatal error: Function name must be a string`

Line in question is `$response = $next($request,$response);` where the `$next` is an empty array.

Slim version 3

```
namespace RealEstate\CommunicationService\Middleware;


use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

class SecuredRouteMiddleware
{
    const SCOPE_NAME = 'messages';

    public function __construct(Client $guzzle){
        $this->guzzle = $guzzle;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request,Response $response,$next){
        $response = $next($request,$response);
        $uacResponse = $this->guzzle->request('GET','http://rees-uac.dev/resource/'.self::SCOPE_NAME.'/validate',[
            'headers' => [
                'Authentication' => $request->getHeader('Authentication')
            ]
        ]);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Comment: This $response = $next($request, $response) line is so strange. Why would you need that?

Comment: To quote the documentation

`It can do whatever is appropriate with these objects. The only hard requirement is that a middleware MUST return an instance of \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface. Each middleware SHOULD invoke the next middleware and pass it Request and Response objects as arguments.` You got me thinking what happens when i don't call it. BRB

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by using declaration of route middleware from Slim2

There you could do `$app->get('route','Middleware','Callback')`

But in SF3 you ought to declare it like `$app->get('route','Callback')->add('Middleware')`

This caused the application to think the middleware is actually the callback.